# Can I represent Antarctica/Troll using C# TimeZoneInfo?

Tags: c#, timezone

I was wondering if there's any way to represent the Antarctica/Troll time zone using the TimeZoneInfo and TimeZoneInfo.AdjustmentRule classes in C#?

It appears that the adjustment rules only support a single annual transition into or out of DST, whereas Antarctica/Troll has *two* transitions each way annually.

There is a first transition where the clock goes forward one hour, then a second transition where it goes forward another hour. Then for the duration of "DST", it is 2 hours ahead of standard time. Toward the end of the year it transitions back to standard time in two steps, "falling back" 1 hour each time.

Comment: It's been a while since I looked in detail at these... but do you definitely need a `TimeZoneInfo`? If you're happy to use [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org), we've definitely got you covered. I realize this may not be an option, but I wanted to highlight it as a possibility...

Comment: I can't use Noda Time, but it's not a huge deal if I can't do it, either...I'm asking more out of a sense of OCD completion than anything else.

Comment: The short answer is - no.  I'll post a longer answer later.  Try Noda Time.  ;)